# How can I ignore the order of letters for data comparison purposes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner at using pandas. Right now I'm looking to compare two lists of chemical compounds (extracted from two differentmaterials databases).

My question is, how can I bypass the order of element in each compound to look for overlaps, since these compounds basically have the same values (Egap and density in this case), but they just appear in different formulas? Example shown in the screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oigze.png)

I hope there is a simple way to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: A `set()` will contain the distinct members and may be a path forward. Give some stuff a try and add your code to this post (the actual text of your code not an image) and someone is sure you point you in the right direction.

Comment: You might also check out `collections.Counter()`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the sub-compounds (in the `Xx` format) with a regex, then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Compound': ['HoC(NO)', 'CHoNO', 'CsFeO', '(FeO)Cs']})

df['unique'] = (df['Compound'].str.extractall('([A-Z][a-z]*)')[0]
                 .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
               )
```

Output:

```
  Compound unique
0  HoC(NO)  CHoNO
1    CHoNO  CHoNO
2    CsFeO  CsFeO
3  (FeO)Cs  CsFeO
```

Alternatively, using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
df['unique'] = (df['Compound'].str.extractall('([A-Z][a-z]*)')[0]
                 .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: frozenset(Counter(x).items()))
               )
```

Output:

```
  Compound                             unique
0  HoC(NO)  ((Ho, 1), (N, 1), (O, 1), (C, 1))
1    CHoNO  ((Ho, 1), (N, 1), (O, 1), (C, 1))
2    CsFeO         ((Cs, 1), (Fe, 1), (O, 1))
3  (FeO)Cs         ((Cs, 1), (Fe, 1), (O, 1))
```

Comment: I used the first option (extractall) and it turns out just how I want it. Thanks alot!